I can't apply gridmask
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

grid_mask = np.zeros((5,5,1))
grid_mask[2, 2] = 1

dataset_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/FracAtlas/images/Fractured/"
destination_folder = "/content/drive/MyDrive/FracAtlas/images/masked/masked_images"

os.makedirs(destination_folder, exist_ok=True)

images = []
for filename in os.listdir(dataset_path):
  image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dataset_path, filename))
  images.append(image)

for i, image in enumerate(images):
  masked_image = image * grid_mask
  cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(destination_folder, f"masked_image_{i}.jpg"), masked_image)

I want to apply a grid mask to broken bones to eliminate the imbalance in my dataset. However I am getting the following error.
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-affc2114a071> in <cell line: 23>()
     22 # Apply the grid mask to each image and save it
     23 for i, image in enumerate(images):
---> 24   masked_image = image * grid_mask
     25   cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(destination_folder, f"masked_image_{i}.jpg"), masked_image)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (454,373,3) (5,5,1)


It is mismatch in the shapes of the image and the grid mask when trying to perform element-wise multiplication.
Try modifying below part of the code
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    
    resized_grid_mask = cv2.resize(grid_mask, (image.shape[1],image.shape[0]))
    masked_image = image * resized_grid_mask
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(destination_folder, f"masked_image_{i}.jpg"), masked_image)


I'm still getting the same error.
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (454,373,3) (454,373)
